# Access servlet declared HttpSession in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, httpsession

If the username, password and location are correct in login servlet i am creating a HttpSession and get to the jsp page. Below is the code in servlet:

```
    HttpSession sessionsa = request.getSession(true);
    sessionsa.setAttribute("user",userName); //userName is a String variable
    sessionsa.setAttribute("location",location); //location in value place is a String variable
```

Now on jsp page I am not able to access the attributes. Code on jsp:

```
    sessionsa = request.getSession();
    String user = (String) sessionsa.getAttribute("user");
    String location = (String) sessionsa.getAttribute("location");
```

It states that cannot find symbol variable sessionsa in class SimplifiedJSPServlet. Please help. Have been googling it since 2 days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do like this,first make the session creation false in your jsp.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" session="false"%>
```

Then to get the session,

```
<%
HttpSession sessionsa = request.getSession(false);
String user = (String) sessionsa.getAttribute("user");
String location = (String) sessionsa.getAttribute("location");
%>
```

By this you will get the user and location from the session.Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use `session` variable (HttpSession object associated with the request), it is available as [Implicit Objects](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm) in JSP.You can use session object without any initialization or getSession().

`session` object is available in JSP if you haven't include below line in JSP

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

It will disable session tracking in JSP file in which it is included.If this line is included in JSP you cant able to used `session` object in JSP directly.

From Rererence doc:

```
JSP Implicit Objects are the Java objects that the JSP Container makes available 
to developers in each page and developer can call them directly without being   
explicitly declared.
```

In your case you can used below code.

```
String user = (String) session.getAttribute("user");
String location = (String) session.getAttribute("location");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also try to directly fetch values using session variable which is pre defined in scope of every jsp:

```
(String)session.getAttribute("name");
```